# Unstable Json data when putting them into TextView and ImageView

Tags: java, android, json, android-recyclerview

i'm tyring to get some informations from *Tumblr* blogs using *Tumblr API* ,now i'm tyring to get Name (*blog_name*) and Image Cover (*Header_image*) from `Json` below

[Json Tree Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DQDa.png)

my code below works fine but when i set **Name** and **ImageCover** into `TextView` and `ImageView` something weird happening ,i find name of first blog in 3rd `recyclview` item or 4th the same thing for Image cover, also when
i scroll top to bottom of `recyclview` the name and image change randomly i do not know why.

here's **myAdapterTumblr.java** ,and
sorry if I dont explain well

```
public class myAdapterTumblr extends RecyclerView.Adapter<myAdapterTumblr.ViewHolder> {

    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    TextView name;
    private List<PostTumblr> postTumblrs;
    private Context context;
    private RecyclerViewClickListenerTumblr mClickListener;
    private String APIKey = "";

    public myAdapterTumblr(List<PostTumblr> postTumblrs, Context context, RecyclerViewClickListenerTumblr clickListener) {
        this.postTumblrs = postTumblrs;
        this.context = context;
        this.mClickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public List<PostTumblr> getItems() {
        return postTumblrs;
    }


    @Override
    public myAdapterTumblr.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tumblr_profil,
                parent, false);

        return new myAdapterTumblr.ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindModel(postTumblrs.get(position));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postTumblrs.size();
    }

    public void getJsonDataCover(PostTumblr mPost, final RequestOptions options, final ProgressBar progressBarCover, final ImageView imgcover) {
        String jsonStr = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + mPost.getTumblrname() + ".tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=" + APIKey;
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, jsonStr, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                try {
                    String cover = null;
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
                    JSONObject response = obj.getJSONObject("response");
                    JSONArray posts = response.getJSONArray("posts");

                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); ++i) {
                        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONArray trail = post.getJSONArray("trail");
                        for (int j = 0; j < trail.length(); ++j) {
                            JSONObject trailobj = trail.getJSONObject(j);
                            JSONObject blog = trailobj.getJSONObject("blog");
                            JSONObject theme = blog.getJSONObject("theme");
                            cover = theme.getString("header_image");
                            Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
                                    .load(cover)
                                    .apply(options)
                                    .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                            return false;
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                            progressBarCover.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }).into(imgcover);
                        }

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    private void getJsonDataText(PostTumblr mPost, final TextView nametv) {
        String jsonStr = "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + mPost.getTumblrname() + ".tumblr.com/posts/photo?api_key=" + APIKey;
        final StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, jsonStr, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);
                    JSONObject response = obj.getJSONObject("response");
                    JSONArray posts = response.getJSONArray("posts");
                    String name = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); ++i) {
                        JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);
                        name = post.getString("blog_name");
                    }
                    nametv.setText(name);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                }
        );
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        PostTumblr mPost;
        ImageView image, imgcover;
        ProgressBar progressBarProfile, progressBarCover;
        TextView facebooktv;
        TextView instagramtv;
        TextView siettv;

        ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
            imgcover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.coverpic);
            progressBarProfile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressprofile);
            progressBarCover = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progresscover);
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            facebooktv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fb);
            instagramtv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.instagram);
            siettv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tumblr);
            progressBarProfile.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            progressBarCover.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
            v.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
        void bindModel(final PostTumblr postTumblr) {
            /*profil*/
            this.mPost = postTumblr;
            final RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
            options.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .priority(Priority.HIGH)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .dontTransform();
            Glide.with(context).asBitmap()
                    .load("https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/" + postTumblr.getTumblrname() + ".tumblr.com/avatar/512")
                    .apply(options)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<Bitmap>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Object model, Target<Bitmap> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressBarProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }).into(image);
            getJsonDataText(mPost, name);
            getJsonDataCover(mPost, options, progressBarCover, imgcover);
            facebooktv.setText(mPost.getTumblrname());
            instagramtv.setText(mPost.getTumblrname());
            siettv.setText(mPost.getTumblrname() + ".tumblr.com");

        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mClickListener.onClick(view, mPost);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misplacing code implementation of data-fetching.

`RecyclerView` (as its name comes with it) reuse the views it creates, so when the data is being fetched asynchronously after a while the view may not belong to the data that have been fetched.

To solve the problem you should move data-fetching codes outside the `myAdapterTumblr` codes, and once all the data have been fetched set the data into the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of the adapter.